# Animating div element size after loading content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link and an empty div element:

```
 <div class='content'>
    <a href='#' onclick="loadData('about')">About</a>
    <div id='data'>
    </div>
  </div>
```

when a user clicks on on 'About' link a javascript function triggers and loads xml data of innerHTML of `<div id='data'>`, as a result:

```
    <div class='content'>
       <a href='#' onclick="loadData('about')">About</a>
       <div id='data'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
 eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
 minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
 voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
 sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
 mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

could you please tell me how can I animate div size?
My css looks like this:

```
.content {
    color: white;
    border: 6px double white;
    min-width: 400px;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: #2f5afc;
    box-shadow: 0 1em 4em -1em black;
    text-shadow: black 0 0 4px;
}
p {
    height: 12em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 1em;
    line-height: 160%;
}
```

A JQuery library is not used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are catering to modern browsers, then you can use the [`transition`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) css property:

```
transition: all 0.25s linear 0s;
```

Below is a snippet that shows how it could work in practice.

```js
var strings = {
  'about' : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
};
var data = document.getElementById("data");
var open = false;
function test(area) {
  open = !open;
  if(open) {
    data.innerHTML = '<p>' + strings[area] + '</p>';
    data.style.height = '12em';
  } else {
    data.innerHTML = '<p></p>';
    data.style.height = '1em';
  }
}
document.getElementById("loadAbout").onclick = function(){
  test('about');
}
```

```css
.content {
    color: white;
    border: 6px double white;
    min-width: 400px;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: #2f5afc;
    box-shadow: 0 1em 4em -1em black;
    text-shadow: black 0 0 4px;
    transition: all 0.25s linear 0s;
}
#data {
    height: 1em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.25s linear 0s;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <a href='#' id="loadAbout">About</a>
  <div id='data'>
  </div>
</div>
```